# Confusion about select()

Tags: c, sockets, select

I'm busy with this for 2 days now and still don't understand it. **What does `select()` do in this code?**

I know that if there is an incoming connection that can be accepted, the `copy.fd_array[]` will contain `ListenSocket` but when the while loop repeats it's still there. So how do we know if a client is disconnected? What does `fd_set copy` contain after the `select()` call?

```
fd_set master;
FD_ZERO(&master);
FD_SET(ListenSocket, &master);

while (1)
{
    fd_set copy = master;

    select(FD_SETSIZE, &copy, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    for (int i = 0; i < FD_SETSIZE; i++)
    {    
        // If new connection
        if (FD_ISSET(ListenSocket, &copy)) 
        {
            printf("[+] New connection\n");
            // Accept connection
            SOCKET AcceptedClient = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
            FD_SET(AcceptedClient, &master);

            // Send welcome message to client
            char buff[128] = "Hello Client!";
            send(AcceptedClient, buff, sizeof(buff), 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html)?

Comment: @G.M. I did but it's still confusing.

Comment: I don't think you can portably assign `fd_set` objects like that, or treat them as arrays. Use `FD_ISSET()` to see if a given descriptor is set in one.

Comment: @Shawn You're right I edited my code

Comment: When all else fails, and you can stomach the corny humor, there's always [Beej's Guide](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/#select) if you're looking for insights into near-everything socket-programming-wise.

Comment: As a general note: for any network function, *check the return value*! Both for errors, and for different success conditions. *If* there is an error, you can use `perror("any identifying text");` to print the error message, that will help you debugging a lot.

Comment: As a side note, I personally find [`poll`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) to be nicer to use than `select`, but that's mostly just a matter of taste.

Comment: @hyde poll and select are very simillar, I guess? If I understand select, then poll is gonna be easy

Comment: It's `WSAPoll()` in winsock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm busy with this for 2 days now and still don't understand it.

It's no wonder that you don't understand the code: The code in the example is nonsense.

Checking the `ListenSocket` should be done outside the `for` loop. And `FD_ISSET` must also be checked for the connections accepted using `accept`.

The correct code inside the `while` loop would look like this:

```
fd_set copy = master;

select(FD_SETSIZE, &copy, NULL, NULL, NULL);

// If new connection
if (FD_ISSET(ListenSocket, &copy)) 
{
    ...
}

for (int i = 0; i < FD_SETSIZE; i++)
{    
    // If an existing connection has data
    // or the connection has been closed
    if ((i != ListenSocket) && FD_ISSET(i, &copy)) 
    {
        nBytes = recv(i, buffer, maxBytes, 0);
        // Connection dropped
        if(nBytes < 1)
        {
            close(i); // other OSs (Linux, MacOS ...)
            // closesocket(i); // Windows
            FD_CLR(i, &master);
        }
        // Data received
        else
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

> I know that if there is an incoming connection that can be accepted, the `copy.fd_array[]` will contain `ListenSocket` but when the `while` loop repeats it's still there.
> What does fd_set copy contain after the select() call?

First of all: Before calling `select()`, `copy.fd_array[]` must contain all socket handles that you are interested in. This means it must contain `ListenSocket` and **all** handles returned by `accept()`.

`master.fd_array[]` contains all these handles, so `fd_set copy = master;` will ensure that `copy.fd_array[]` also contains all these handles.

`select()` (with `NULL` as last argument) will wait until at least one socket becomes "available". This means that it will wait until at least one of the following conditions is true:

- A connection accepted using `accept()` is closed by the other side
- a connection accepted using `accept()` has data that can be received
- there is a new connection that can be accepted using `accept(ListenSocket...)`

As soon as one condition is fulfilled, `select()` **removes** all other handles from `copy.fd_array[]`:

- `ListenSocket` is removed from `copy.fd_array[]` if there is no incoming connection
- A handle returned by `accept()` is removed from that array if the connection has neither been closed nor new data is available

If two events happen the same time, `copy.fd_array[]` will contain more than one handle.

You use `FD_ISSET()` to check if some handle is still in the array.

> So how do we know if a client is disconnected?

When you detect `FD_ISSET(i, &copy)` for a value `i` that has been returned by `accept()`, you must call `recv()` (under Linux `read()` would also work):

If `recv()` returns 0 (or negative in the case of errors), the other computer has dropped the connection. You must call `close()` (`closesocket()` on Windows) and remove the handle from `copy.fd_array[]` (this means: you must remove it from `master.fd_array[]` because of the line `fd_set copy = master;`).

If `recv()` returns a positive value, this is the number of bytes that have been received.

Comment: Appreciate it, it's clear now thank you.